# Formik Yup showing error even when it meets the requirement

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik, yup

I want the `TextInput` to validate exactly 16 digits.  I've tried the following:

```
yup.number()
  .test('len', 'Must be exactly 16 numbers', val => val.length === 16)
```

But, every time I type anything into the field, I get the following:

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection

I tried the following instead:

```
yup.number().max(16)
```

But, even when I input 16 digits exactly, it will still throw an error saying that it must be less or equal to 16 characters.

The updated the implementation:

```
<Formik
   initialValues={{ someInput: Number }}
   onSubmit={submitHandler}
   validationSchema={yup.object().shape({
   someInput: yup
       .number()
       .test('len', 'Must be exactly 16 numbers', val => val.toString().length === 16)
       .positive()
       .integer()
       .required(),
})>
```

Following is my `TextInput`

```
                                           <TextInput
                                                value={values.someInput}
                                                onChangeText={handleChange('someInput')}
                                                onBlur={() => setFieldTouched('someInput')}
                                                placeholder="some input"
                                                style={styles.someInput}
                                            />
                                            {touched.someInput && errors.someInput &&
                                                <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, color: 'red' }}>{errors.someInput}</Text>
                                            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because numbers do not have a `length` property.  You'd need to convert it to a string first.  Also, checking for `max` on a number will error out on any number greater than 16, not a number more than 16 digits long.

```
yup.number()
  .test('len', 'Must be exactly 16 numbers', val => val.toString().length === 16)
```

Comment: I also have `yup.number().positive().integer().require()` and initialized it with either `inputExample: ''` or `inputExample: Number`, but even if I input just numbers, I get the error message `it must be an integer`

Comment: Well ```''``` is a string so that would not pass. But I'd need to see an example of how you're using it, since it's probably due to your implementation. I've never used the integer test but it looks fine.

Comment: Can you post the input component you're using to interact with it? You may need to call ```parseInt()``` on your values inside your ```onChange``` function.  Also make sure your initial value is a positive integer, not ```Number```.

Comment: how do I set my initial value to be a positive integer?

Comment: ```initialValues={{ someInput: 1 }}```